# COMODO Antivirus Considers a Python File a Threat

Tags: python, antivirus, anaconda

I am using COMODO antivirus on my ubuntu partition, and recently ran a scan.  It found a HIGH PRIORITY error which seems like nothing more than a file in numpy.  [image: ThreatReport]

Has anyone else seen this before?

(1) What causes it?

(2) Is it safe to ignore?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Has anyone else seen this before?

[1 hit on google](http://lists.scilab.org/pipermail/bugzilla/2014-August/035310.html) for Exploit.JS.Pdfka. Nobody even bothered answering that bug report except for an [update your virus database file](http://lists.scilab.org/pipermail/bugzilla/2014-August/035358.html).

Upload the file to [virustotal](https://virustotal.com/) for an online scan. Those are a lot better than off line virus scanners.

- What causes it?

Comodo is a stupid piece of software that relies on malware and anti-virus that appear on a Windows machine to behave the same on Linux? `io.py` is probably used in a malware and now it believes all `io.py`'s are malware?

- Is it safe to ignore?

99.99999999% of all notices from anti-virus software are false positives.

If you want to use an anti-virus install a 2nd anti-virus and compare results. Only when both alarm about the same file I would investigate it.

Comment: What about uploading the file to an online multi-engine malware scanner like https://virustotal.com ?

Comment: Regarding the two anti-virus softwares.  I did that on my Windows 7 PC when I first got it and it caused massive problems (slowdowns and crashes).  The Tech support hotline said that the two anti-viruses "fight."  When I deleted one, the problems went away.  Are you sure it's a good idea?